# Are heat sinks necessary for a Triac even in low current circuit?

Tags: current, triac

Triacs tend to get hot in circuit when operating. The temperature can be determined with estimated output current. In my understanding, with low current output, a Triac can operate within maximum operate temperature without heatsinks. But is it safe to do so? I can't find anyone or any video online ever using a Triac without a heatsink.

If it is safe, is there a rule of thumb of such power limit or current limit for Triac to operate solely? Or I just need to look at the data sheet to determine this limit myself?

Comment: Look at the data sheet, and consider that diode voltage drop may be 2 V. The tab itself is a  bit of a heatsink, and most semiconductors the size of a triac with tab can dissipate at least 0.5 W in free air at STP. At a guess, for 200 mA or less, skip the heat sink.

Comment: No a heatsink is not always necessary, I do it all the time, especially for pulse applications. But in a real application, it may be more cost effective to use a smaller Triac with a heatsink than a larger Triac without a heatsink.

Comment: Is this circuit for yourself, or for production? For myself, if a component is too hot to touch, then I use a heat sink, even if the component is within the safe-operating area temperature-wise. I like to touch my components, and I don't like to get burned. If you are doing a commercial project, the price/bulk/weight of heatsinks needs to be evaluated with the extra component life-time they will yield. Obviously if safe operation area is violated without a heatsink, you need one.

Comment: In my washing machine 2 out of 6 or 7 triacs have heatsinks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Basic Idea

Triacs are three-terminal semiconductor devices designed for controlling current in both the positive and negative halves of an AC cycle.

Like many semiconductor devices, triacs dissipate power in the form of heat when they operate.

The power dissipated by a triac when it's conducting can be calculated by the formula:

\$
P = I * V
\$

Where:

- `P` is the power dissipation in watts (W).
- `I` is the current through the triac in amperes (A).
- `V` is the voltage drop across the triac when it's on, typically 1 to 2 volts for many triacs.

To check if a triac needs a heatsink at a given current, you should refer to its datasheet. Look for a parameter called `Thermal Resistance junction to ambient` (\$R_{θ j-A}\$ or \$R_{th j-A}\$). This value indicates how much the temperature of the triac's junction will rise for every watt of power it dissipates, usually given in °C/Watt or Kelvin/Watt.

- For instance, for the [BT136 triac from NXP](https://cdn.hackaday.io/files/1819267783521984/BT136.pdf), `Thermal Resistance junction to ambient` is specified as:

[image: Thermal Resistance junction to ambient]

\$R_{θ j-a} = 60 Kelvin/Watt\$ or \$R_{θ j-a} = 60°C/Watt\$

- We also need the `On state Voltage` or \$V_{t}\$ of the triac. For the BT136 from NXP, it is:

[image: On state Voltage]

\$V_{t} = 1.70V_{max}\$

- We also need the `Maximum Junction Temperature` (\$T_{jmax}\$), as an example, for the BT136 triac from NXP, it is specified as:

[image: Maximum Junction Temperature]

\$T_{jmax} = 125°C\$

#### Let's Take an Example

Assume you're supplying 200VAC (RMS) to the triac and driving a 100W light bulb (resistive), and the triac we are using is BT136 from NXP.

1. *Calculate the RMS Current through the Bulb*:

Using the formula \$P = V_{rms} \times I_{rms}\$:

\$I_{rms} = P / V_{rms} = 100W / 200V = 0.5A\$

2. *Estimate Power Dissipation in the Triac*:

Using the formula \$P_{triac} = I_{rms} \times V_t\$ and the worst-case \$V_t\$ of 1.7V for BT136:

\$P_{triac} = 0.5A \times 1.7V = 0.85W\$

3. *Calculate the Rise in Junction Temperature*:

Given the thermal resistance junction-to-ambient of 60K/W or 60°C/W:

\$ΔT = P_{triac} \times R_{θ j-a} = 0.85W \times 60°C/W = 51°C\$

4. *Estimate the Junction Temperature*:

If the ambient temperature is 36.85°C (or 310K), the junction temperature would be:

\$
   T_{junction} = T_{ambient} + ΔT = 36.85°C + 51°C = 87.85°C
   \$

5. *Compare with Maximum Junction Temperature (\$T_{jmax}\$)*:

   The BT136 triac from NXP has a maximum junction temperature (\$T_{jmax}\$*)​ of 125°C. Given our calculated junction temperature of 87.85°C, the triac is operating within its specified limit.

However, 87.85°C is still considerably hot, and for prolonged or continuous operation, using a heatsink is suggested to prevent excessive heat buildup and ensure longevity of the device.

This approach helps to determine whether the triac will operate within safe temperature limits for a given load and ambient temperature.

#### Pulsed Operation

If you pulse a triac, for example with a 50% duty cycle at 2Hz, the thermal characteristics can be different than continuous operation. Let's calculate that.

1. Pulse Duration: Since it's a 50% duty cycle at 2Hz, each pulse is \$ \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2Hz} = 0.25 \$ seconds or 250ms.
2. Pulse Frequency: 2Hz.
3. Pulse Period: \$ \frac{1}{2Hz} = 0.5 \$ seconds.
4. We previously calculated the power dissipation for continuous operation as \$ P_{triac} = 0.85W \$.

Now, for a 50% duty cycle, `Average Power Dissipation`:

Given by the formula: \$ P_{avg} = \frac{P_{pulse} \times \text{pulse duration}}{\text{pulse period}} \$

Plugging in our numbers: \$ P_{avg} = \frac{0.85W \times 0.25s}{0.5s} \$

\$ P_{avg} = 0.425W \$

So, for a 50% duty cycle at 2Hz, the average power dissipation over time is 0.425W.

At higher frequencies, a triac experiences more switching losses during transitions between 'on' and 'off' states, due to simultaneous high transient voltage and current. This leads to increased power dissipation and heat. Gate drive and conduction losses also contribute.

Comment: 15 Volts - Hi, Thanks for writing an answer. However, your answer was missing the [required](/help/referencing) link back to the source datasheet that you copied. To help you, I found what I *think* is the same datasheet that you copied from and I added that link. (If you want to change that link, please edit it.) Please note that it's your responsibility to include references for copied/adapted material which you use, as explained in that site rule :) Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's completely safe provided you limit the current to the triac in some way to a sufficiently low level for the conditions and requirements.

For example, if you have a typical TO-220 16A triac [BTA-16](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/67/06/bc/c9/35/8e/4f/ea/CD00002265.pdf/files/CD00002265.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00002265.pdf) and are controlling a 200W 220VAC heater the 'on' current will be about 0.9A RMS, resulting in about 0.9W power dissipation maximum according to Fig 2.

[image]

The TO-220 packaged part has a ThetaJ-A of 60°C/W so the temperature rise without a heatsink will be about 54°C. If you want the junction temperature to be less than (say) 100°C for reliability, then it will be okay up to an ambient temperature of 46°C, and absolute maximum (125°C Tj) will typically occur at an ambient temperature of about 70°C. That's probably acceptable in many cases.
However a bit of copper on the PCB can make it quite a bit better at very little cost (or use the TO-252 with some copper to get 45°C/W and the numbers above become about 60°C and 85°C respectively, much better.

You need to be a bit careful to explore the assumptions in the ThetaJ-a numbers for SMT parts- they typically assume a fair bit of copper area and if you provide less you'll get less heat-sinking (and the junction will run hotter than expected).

You would use similar equations to calculate the *size* of the heatsink you would require if one is required, except you'd typically ignore the dissipation by the package itself unless the heatsink spec includes it (eg. clip-on TO-220 heatsink) and add the ThetaJ-c junction-to-case to the thermal resistance of the heatsink case-to-ambient (from the heatsink datasheet and taking care to understand the assumptions therein). If you are making your own heatsink you can use rough formulas, empirical measurements or try to do fluid dynamics heat flow simulations. Empirical measurements are probably best unless you are doing this sort of thing all the time.

Answer (score 5):

Triac,  typically about 2V between MT1 and MT2 when conducting, so 1A conducted is 2W dissipated, 2W is typically fine in TO220 parts in still air.

I used a TO92 triac in an RS232 powered RS232 to relay circuit. that only ever passed fraction of an amp for a fraction of a second once every few seconds, so no problem there.

The thing about adding a heatsink is that when you're designing a switch or dimmer adding a heatsink increases the capability of the device at little cost.   when you're designing an appliance you know what the maximum load is and excess capacity only adds cost with no benefit.